# Conda change environment automatically when changing folder in powershell

Tags: python, powershell, conda, environment

I use PowerShell and python. As I have multiple project, I have also multiple conda environment.

I want to create a way to automatically change my environment based on the folder.
For the moment, I code :

```sh
function conda_here {
  $first_line = Get-Content -Head 1 environment.yml  # This returns "name: conda_env_name"
  $env_name = $first_line.Split(": ")[-1]  # This splits it into an array of [name, : , conda_env_name] and takes the last element
  try {
    conda activate $env_name
  } catch {
    Write-Host "Tried to activate environment $env_name, but failed." -ForeGroundColor Red
  }
}

function cda () {
    set-location @args 
    if ( Test-Path environment.yml ){
        conda_here 
    }
}
```

So I use `cda my_folder`.

Problem, when I enter directly in the folder (using Pycharm, VSCode or open in with Terminal) the `cda` doesn't work (it “up to ~”). I will prefer to “override” `cd` but it doesn't work when changing `cda` to `cd`.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution when checking around on some "changing CD behavior". Here is my success :

```sh
function conda_here {
  $first_line = Get-Content -Head 1 environment.yml
  $env_name = $first_line.Split(': ')[-1] 
  try { conda activate $env_name }
  catch { Write-Host "Tried to activate environment $env_name, but failed." -ForegroundColor Red }
}

if (Test-Path environment.yml) { conda_here }

function cda () {
  Set-Location @args 
  if (Test-Path environment.yml) { conda_here }
  else { conda activate Root }    
}

Set-Item Alias:cd cda
```

I put this in my `$PROFILE`

NB: `Root` is my conda "basic" (I don't use `base`) because I use pip package sometimes without specific project/code.
You can remove the line or change it if you need.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great use for the `prompt` function.  This get's executed after any operation in PowerShell, and also renders the PowerShell prompt.

Here's the basic one in PowerShell.

```
function prompt { 'PS ' + $(get-location) + '> ' }
```

Here's a more advanced one, which ships with the awesome DBA Tools PowerShell module.

```
function Prompt
{
    Write-Host "[" -NoNewline
    Write-Host (Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss") -ForegroundColor Gray -NoNewline
    
    try
    {
        $history = Get-History -ErrorAction Ignore
        if ($history)
        {
            Write-Host "][" -NoNewline
            if (([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'Sqlcollaborative.Dbatools.Utility.DbaTimeSpanPretty').Type)
            {
                Write-Host ([Sqlcollaborative.Dbatools.Utility.DbaTimeSpanPretty]($history[-1].EndExecutionTime - $history[-1].StartExecutionTime)) -ForegroundColor Gray -NoNewline
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host ($history[-1].EndExecutionTime - $history[-1].StartExecutionTime) -ForegroundColor Gray -NoNewline
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
    Write-Host "] $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.ProviderPath)" -NoNewline
    "> "
}
```

[image]

Now, if you just wanted to take the basic normal prompt and run your code, here is how it would work.

```
function prompt { 'PS ' + $(get-location) + '> ' 
    if ( Test-Path environment.yml ){
        conda_here 
    }
}
```

This way, your code will automatically run when you change directories.  If the directory contains an `environment.yml`, it will automatically call `conda_here` for you.

To save this as your default when you launch PowerShell, add it to your PowerShell profile.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for the reply. How can I use / charge oh my posh ? If I add 
```sh
Import-Module oh-my-posh
 Invoke-Expression oh-my-posh init pwsh --config C:\Users\etulyon1\AppData\Local\oh-my-posh\themes\stelbent.minimal.omp.json
```
After the commands, the function to change the environment doesn't work :(

Comment: Oh-my-posh completely changes the behavior of the PowerShell prompt, you would need to look at its docs to see if it allows arbitrary code execution.